# Warning: View is not in Window Hierarchy in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, presentviewcontroller

I am doing a Xamarin project, Forms and I have integrated Xam.Plugins.Messaging to send SMS from my app. For this I have created a custom renderer in my iOS project with below code:

```
AppDelegate smsObj = new AppDelegate();
bool a= smsObj.ShowAndSendSMS(new string[] { "123" }, "Hi there");
```

And in my AppDelegate, I have the code as below:

```
public bool ShowAndSendSMS(string[] recipients, string body)
{
      UIViewController sms = new UIViewController();
      if (MFMessageComposeViewController.CanSendText)
      {
           MFMessageComposeViewController message = new MFMessageComposeViewController();
           message.Finished += (sender, e) => {
           message.DismissViewController(true, null);
      };
      message.Body = body;
      message.Recipients = recipients;
      sms.PresentModalViewController(message, false);
   }
   return true;
 }
```

The problem I am facing is on my first-time app launch, the functionality to share SMS doesn't work and the debug log gives me warning like "Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"

However, if I restart the app, the same functionality works like a charm. Any ideas from where i have made mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with the fact that you're newing up an AppDelegate and calling the ShowAndSendSMS from there.  iOS is going to new up that AppDelegate for you upon app startup, and you should always use that, as opposed to creating a new instance of AppDelegate (at least I've never seen a situation that called for a multi-AppDelegate-instance pattern).  So, try this:

Create a helper class in your project like this (I don't really like the word "helper", but that's beside the point; name it something fitting for your project):

```
using Foundation;
using UIKit;

public class SmsHelper
{
    public bool ShowAndSendSMS(string[] recipients, string body)
    {
        if (MFMessageComposeViewController.CanSendText)
        {
            UIViewController sms = new UIViewController();

            MFMessageComposeViewController message = new MFMessageComposeViewController();
            message.Finished += (sender, e) => {
                message.DismissViewController(true, null);
            };
            message.Body = body;
            message.Recipients = recipients;
            sms.PresentModalViewController(message, false);
        }
        return true;
    }  
}
```

And then change your page renderer to consume it like this:

```
public class SMS_Ios: PageRenderer 
{
    private readonly TaskScheduler uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e) 
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        SmsHelper smsObj = new SmsHelper();

        bool a = smsObj.ShowAndSendSMS(new string[] {"123"}, "Hi there");
    }
}
```

And finally, remove ShowAndSendSMS from your AppDelegate.cs, since you'll be using your SMS helper going forward.

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Here you go: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ncd9r2za3voeewu/AppDelegate.cs?dl=0

Comment: Thanks!  Also, where are you doing the AppDelegate smsObj = new AppDelegate() line?  You shouldn't be newing up another AppDelegate instance.  Try either refactoring ShowAndSendSMS out into some SMS helper class, or creating a static singleton to hold the AppDelegate instance that Mono spins up for you, and you can use that reference throughout your code.  Personally, I'd go with the SMS helper class from a separation of responsibilities standpoint.

Comment: So I have created custom renderer in my iOS project where I am creating an instance for AppDelegate as below:  
    `public class SMS_Ios : PageRenderer
    {
        private readonly TaskScheduler uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            AppDelegate smsObj = new AppDelegate();
            bool a= smsObj.ShowAndSendSMS(new string[] { "123" }, "Hi there");
         }           
    }
}`

Comment: Any idea what should I do to create a helper class?

Comment: I edited my answer to describe what the full solution would look like.

Comment: It is still not working and giving me error like " Warning: Attempt to present <MFMessageComposeViewController: 0x111133400> on <Xamarin_Forms_Platform_iOS_ModalWrapper: 0x10f446040> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!" Does it have anything to do with the plugin which I am using ?

Comment: I am using the below code in my app page to use the SMS share functionality:   `var smsMessenger = CrossMessaging.Current.SmsMessenger;`
           `var message = "abc";`
           `if (smsMessenger.CanSendSms)`
                `smsMessenger.SendSms("", message);`   Do you think the renderer will be called from that code?

Comment: It's kind of hard for me to imagine the context of your code.  If you're willing to share the whole solution, and assuming there aren't a bunch of 3rd party components I need to install, I can see if I can reproduce it on my end.  Would be much easier for me to troubleshoot and isolate the issue.  Just be sure to blank out any API keys, passwords, and other sensitive info. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have already installed the `Xam.Plugins.Messaging` package in the PCL and your platforms. You can just use the API from it in PCL to implement that without any special codes in your iOS platform.

You can just use the APIs of `Xam.Plugins.Messaging` in the PCL, like this:

```
// Send Sms
var smsMessenger = CrossMessaging.Current.SmsMessenger;
if (smsMessenger.CanSendSms)
   smsMessenger.SendSms("+27213894839493", "Well hello there from Xam.Messaging.Plugin");
```

Reference: [Messaging Plugin for Xamarin and Windows](https://components.xamarin.com/view/xam.plugins.messaging).

Comment: I tried that solution but it doesn't work with just Messaging package in iOS. It works perfectly in Android but in iOS its not working for the first app launch.

Comment: The Messaging package works fine for me. Where did you trigger the `smsMessenger.SendSms()`?

Comment: Hi Kevin, I am triggering the smsMessenger.SendSms() in Content Page of my Shared Application Project. So I have a button on whose click I am calling this:  `var smsMessenger = CrossMessaging.Current.SmsMessenger;`
            `var message = "abc";`
            'if (smsMessenger.CanSendSms)'
                'smsMessenger.SendSms("", message);'  Also, can you please tell me what version of plugin you are using?

Comment: I used the last version 4.0.0 on my side.